# How to get detailed status from flask background runner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have to implement a very long (many minutes, perhaps hours) method in my Python Flask API.

I was planning to use flask_executor.
My code is something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_executor import Executor
import uuid
import time
 
app = Flask(__name__)
executor = Executor(app)
 
 
class BackgroundRunner:
    def __init__(self, executor):
        self.executor = executor
 
    def task(self):
        percent_completed = 0
        time.sleep(1000)
        percent_completed = 33
        time.sleep(1000)
        percent_completed = 66
        time.sleep(1000)
        percent_completed = 100
 
    def task_async(self):
        task_id = uuid.uuid4().hex # generate a unique task ID
        task = self.executor.submit(task_id)
        return task_id
 
    def task_status(self, task_id):
        task = self.executor.futures._state(task_id)
        if task.done():
            return "completed"
        else:
            return "running"
 
background_runner = BackgroundRunner(executor)
 
 
@app.route('/slow_task', methods=['POST'])
def slow_task():
    task_id = background_runner.task_async()
    return jsonify({"task_id": task_id})
 
 
@app.route('/slow_task_status/<task_id>')
def slow_task_status(task_id):
    status = background_runner.task_status(task_id)
    return jsonify({"status": status})
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My problem is I need some more info about task completion in slow_task_status, like a percentage value ...
Is this possible using `flask_executor` package?

Comment: Doubtless there's a much more elegant solution, but you could certainly build something that at least works using either **Redis** or a Python Mulitprocessing Manager and throwing some results, or status or percent complete numbers in either of those.

Comment: I'd prefer to "keep it simple"... So I'd avoid Redis, Celery, or other framework, until possible... But I'd be very interested in a much more elegant solution...